# Download, store, view and manage PDF File

Tags: iphone, pdf, uiwebview, filesystems

Can I download a PDF file and shows it without use UIWebView?
I need to show PDF and get full control of its show...

Also, Can I download and strore PDF into filesystem app?

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download a PDF the same way as you would download any other file, using an NSURLConnection or NSData's +dataWithContentsOfURL: method.  This file will be stored within your application's sandboxed documents directory.  Other applications on the filesystem will not have access to it.

As far as viewing the PDF without using UIWebView, this can be accomplished using CGPDFDocument, as described in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93297/newbie-wants-to-create-a-pdf-reader-for-ipod-touch-whats-the-best-approach).