# iphone : how can we store pdf file in local and read it?

Tags: iphone, pdf-generation

i want to store pdf file in local and read it . i want to read this pdf same as iphone read data in mkmapview.

means i want to create same as pdf(Acrobat) reader.how can i do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read a pdf on ipad/iphone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265301/how-to-read-a-pdf-on-ipad-iphone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you need this

http://github.com/akisute/iPhonePDF

from here you can find code (api) by that you can genrate pdf in iphone .

and also can do edit it.

Let me know this is what you need ?

Comment: thank you somuch. after long time but i got the correct ans. this thing help me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

you can store the pdf in the application bundle and display it using a uiwebview:

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 200)];

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"document" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];

[self.view addSubview:webView];
[webView release];
```

to load it from an url you can do something like this:

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 200)];

NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mywebsite.com/myPdfFile.pdf"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];

[self.view addSubview:webView];
[webView release];
```

you can also download your pdf into the documentDirectory during runtime and load it from there.

Comment: ok .thanx but i here apple xcode has inbuilt function for pdf reader like mkmapview. do u have any idea about it ?

Comment: i don't have knowledge of any component similar to mkMapView for reading pdfs in iOS. The only way i know that you can do it is using a UIWebView.

Answer (score -1):

You can open the PDF with iBooks or any other app that can read PDF files to store it locally on the Phone.

Comment: what is iBooks ? can u explain it ? can u give me sample ?